# Sitecore: Add a New Data Template to my Sublayout

Tags: sitecore, datatemplate, sublayout

I sublayout is about Events.
If I put it inside a page which contains an Event, it will display informations pertaining to it.

I want to add a Data Template to my Sublayout that will allow editors to specify one particular Event from which to draw these informations.

---

How do I go about creating a Data Template that allows an editor to choose a specific Event from a list?
How do I add this to a given Sublayout?

Comment: Why don't you use data source?

Comment: Because I am new to SiteCore. If you have a different solution that would work, feel free to suggest.

Comment: This link will help: http://firebreaksice.com/using-the-datasource-field-with-sitecore-sublayouts/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building componentized architectures as you are doing, you will want to implement the datasource property for a sublayout to make your sublayout a datasource-driven sublayout.

This article by John West should help on how to set a datasource:
http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/11/How-to-Apply-Data-Sources-to-Sitecore-ASPNET-Presentation-Components.aspx

The basics are:

1. Create a template for your Event to contain the data
2. On your sublayout item (/sitecore/Layouts/...) set the datasource template property to match to your new Event template.
3. Update your code to pull from the datasource item on the sublayout, not the Sitecore.Context.Item

The following post by Mark Ursino is helpful in seeing the code side as well:
http://firebreaksice.com/using-the-datasource-field-with-sitecore-sublayouts/

Comment: Looking into this, thanks.
Could you shed any light on how to achieve this using the method I outlined above?

Comment: Hello Emanuele, are you asking about how to have them 'choose from a list'?
If so, the most obvious solution would be to ensure you have your Events all stored in a single folder location. You can set the datasource location on your sublayout, along with the datasource template. Then, when users go to choose a datasource, Sitecore will present them with the options in the folder you specified.